# circular Profile picture using Quartzcore framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to make set image to uiimageview circularly.

my uiimageview width and height are 150 and the image i want to set is 50 x 50
Below is the code I have tried:

```
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.profileImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

by using above code i am getting blurred image.

any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You have an image that is 50 by 50 and you're scaling it up to 150 by 150 and you're complaining it's blurry? The code you have will mask the UIImageView to a circle. Do you want the image in the UIImageView to not scale?

Comment: I need clear image..

Comment: Then download a bigger image...

Comment: How can you create high resolution images from low resolution image?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now you want to scale image then use this code..

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;}
```

and then Wherever you set the image like this..

```
self.profileImageView=[self imageWithImage:self.profileImageView.image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
```

I hope this will help for you..

Comment: The above code gives me to clear image for this size ...Your problem is in other code..The profile image size is small.

Comment: yes my image size is 50 X 50 and image view size is 150 X 150.If i set i want clear image not the blurred one